# "Stay Away" how to handle case with 4 Infected cards

Tags: stay-away

Last night I had a game where I was infected by The Thing and drew a Panic! card (Forgetful) which states that I should discard 3 cards and draw 3 more. What happened was that after that Panic! card I had to discard my 3 not infected cards (since I am infected I can't discard the one I have) and I drew 3 Stay Away which happened to be infected cards so I was left with 4 infected cards, but the rules state that you can't have more than 3 in your hand in any given time.

What I thought of was that if a Panic! card doesn't say that it ends your turn you can draw again and continue as normal, but that is not also a viable solution to the problem, because the next card might still be Infected.

Has any of you encountered this situation? Can you give me an idea of what solution I may apply to this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion/workaround is to show everybody that you drew 3 'infected' cards, discard them and draw 3 more cards instead whether you're infected or not. If it's infected cards - do it again.
And yes we actually encountered this situation and it kind of messed the game.